# Is it possible to monitor CPU usage and execute a script if the CPU exceeds a certain amount?

Tags: ubuntu, htop

Using a tool like top or htop, is it possible to monitor CPU usage and execute a script if CPU usage exceeds a certain amount?

Answer (score 1):

This would be trivial using a tool like [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

```
check system myhost
    if cpu usage (system) > 80% for 4 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (user) > 80% for 5 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (wait) > 90% for 5 cycles then alert
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Cfengine can do with classes and variables. Classes use standard deviation which is more flexible that hard limits.
2. I think you can do this with net-snmp too.
3. You can pull loads from sysstat.
4. Raw numbers in /proc/loadavg.